# How does Linux with CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL=y update the system clock

Tags: linux, time, timer, linux-kernel, x86

I'm trying to understand how timekeeping works in the Linux kernel, specifically how the system clock is updated.
I'm running kernel v6.5 with these configurations from `/proc/config.gz`

```
#
# Timers subsystem
#
CONFIG_TICK_ONESHOT=y
CONFIG_NO_HZ_COMMON=y
# CONFIG_HZ_PERIODIC is not set
# CONFIG_NO_HZ_IDLE is not set
CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL=y
CONFIG_CONTEXT_TRACKING_USER=y
# CONFIG_CONTEXT_TRACKING_USER_FORCE is not set
CONFIG_NO_HZ=y
CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y
CONFIG_CLOCKSOURCE_WATCHDOG_MAX_SKEW_US=100
# end of Timers subsystem
...
# CONFIG_HZ_100 is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_250 is not set
CONFIG_HZ_300=y
# CONFIG_HZ_1000 is not set
CONFIG_HZ=300
```

and available clocksources in `/sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource`

```
tsc hpet acpi_pm
```

After reading https://docs.kernel.org/timers/no_hz.html my understanding is as follows:
Because `CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL` is set, all but one of my cores are "running tickless". These cores don't recieve the perdiodic timer interrupt 300 times a second. However, there should still be one core that does handle these interrups and is responsible for updating the system clock.

My `/proc/interrupts` shows these two lines

```
0:         43          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    2-edge      timer
LOC:     230699     223726     237045     125923     251924     120454     232764     139559     224598     122373     208406     122949   Local timer interrupts
```

As far as I understand, the CPU has per core LAPICs that trigger local timer interrupts to e.g. calculate the load on that core. However, I don't understand why there are only 43 timer interrupts on CPU0.
Shouldn't there still be timer interrputs at 300HZ on at least one CPU, that update the system clock and jiffies? If yes, what clocksource is used to schedule this interrupts (TSC, HPET, ACPI PMT, a PIT)?

Comment: The kernel doc you linked mentions timekeeping during NO_HZ_FULL: *At least one non-adaptive-tick CPU must remain online to handle timekeeping tasks in order to ensure that system calls like gettimeofday() returns accurate values on adaptive-tick CPUs*.  I'd expect core #0 uses the "local timer" (LOC) interrupt handler to update the system-wide "coarse" time, since as you say, that's why the kernel doesn't allow all cores to run fully tickless.  (All cores interpolate from the last "coarse" tick using rdtsc)

Comment: On my system (i7-6700k desktop) with a stock Arch GNU/Linux kernel, I see the same thing: 11 IRQ 0 on the first core, none on the rest.  And tons of LOC counts on all cores, with a similar spread to yours, like 17... to 24...   Probably the kernel switches over to LOC interrupts very soon after booting and never looks back, maybe before bringing up the other cores.  Arch sets `CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL=y` in their kernel config, but the default boot options don't use `nohz_full` to enable it for any cores, so all cores just do dyntick-idle, IIUC.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for your answer. Do you have a source for the interpolation with the TSC, you could point me to?

Comment: Single-step into `clock_gettime` with GDB; it's done in user-space in the vDSO.  update: some recent discussion about user-space `clock_gettime` included a link to the source: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.4/source/lib/vdso/gettimeofday.c#L307